# Get file path from internal directory capturing photos

Tags: android, filepath, photos, image-capture

I'm creating an application that after taking a photo, uploads it on a server (using the file path, like the tutorial on https://trinitytuts.com/capture-image-upload-server-android/).

To take the picture I followed the instructions on https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html.

While I capture an image having an external storage, everything works fine, but if I use a device without SD (like a Nexus) app crashes.

Can you help me?
Thank you

EDIT

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.w("error", "ERROR");
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.application.package.fileprovider",//here I put the app pakage
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your camera intent code

Answer (score 1):

Use this while open the camera using intent

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("Log Excepton", ex.toString() + "...");
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }

    }
```

Use this in on activity result

```
if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
   Log.e("Log mCurrentPhotoPath", mCurrentPhotoPath + "...");
   iv_uploadimage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
   selectedImagePath1 = mCurrentPhotoPath.substring(5);
   Log.e("Log Optimized path", selectedImagePath1 + "...");}
```

Add file write permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is for creating file

```
 private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After capturing image you will get the result in the `ActivtyResult`.

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
     Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think have problem in `createImageFile` code.**

**Try with this updated function**

```
/**
 * Function for create file in SD card or internal storage depending on SD card availability
 * @return : file in internal / external storage
 */
private File createImageFile() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // get path of pictures folder from SD card
        // give any path of your choice
        return new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    }else {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        // create folder of your app or get already exists folder
        // ie path from internal storage
        return cw.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add  `permission`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```